# Why won't Intellij recognize Gradle in spring boot starter project?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I was having some issues where I was unable to get a build on a separate springBoot project. I read an online forum that recommended updating to the latest so I bumped it and immediately Intellij stopped recognizing the build.gradle and it was no longer recognized as a build tool. I attempted opening the build.gradle files and invalidating the caches and restarting, but Intellij wouldn't recognize it.

I attempted cloning the gradle spring-boot starter project and I saw the same thing (https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot.git). It did, however, work when I just open the complete subfolder as it's own project. Are there specific steps I should be taking to allow Intellij to mark subprojects and use gradle as my build tool?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was running MacOS High Sierra and there were issues with the latest versions of openJDK and Gradle running on the machine. I ended up having to do a factory reset and getting up to the latest OS to make it work.